# Custom view with <merge> and <layout> tags

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, merge

I tried to use the native Android Studio data binding functionality together with a custom layout. 
My custom layout look like this:

```
public class MainNavigationEntryView extends LinearLayout {

    private MainNavigationEntryBinding layoutBinding;

    public MainNavigationEntryView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }

    [...]

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layoutBinding = MainNavigationEntryBinding.inflate(inflater, this, true);
        [...]
    }
}
```

My layout file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageIcon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/tabbar_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tabbar_icon_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/stateful_background_no_bounds"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:ignore="contentDescription"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageIndicator"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/indicator_size_small"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/indicator_size_small"
            android:src="@drawable/background_circle_blue"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible"
            tools:ignore="contentDescription"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

The problem here is that I have two nested LinearLayout. I tried to reduce it by using the [`<merge>` tag](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html), but it seems that it is not possible to have the `<layout>` and the `<merge>` tag together in one layout.

Is there another way to do it or to have the a `<layout>` and a `<merge>` tag together in one layout?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have a `<layout>` tag nested with a `<merge>`.

But there is one thing you can do to avoid two nested LinearLayout.

Your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.example.MyCustomView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageIcon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/tabbar_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tabbar_icon_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="@drawable/stateful_background_no_bounds"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:ignore="contentDescription"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageIndicator"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/indicator_size_small"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/indicator_size_small"
            android:src="@drawable/background_circle_blue"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible"
            tools:ignore="contentDescription"/>

    </com.example.MyCustomView>
</layout>
```

Your custom view:

```
public class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout {

    private MyCustomViewBinding binding;

    public MyCustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    [...]

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        binding = MyCustomViewBinding.bind(this);
    }

}
```